# Undefined Reference To 'function

Tags: c++, templates, error-handling

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void doStuff();

int main() {
    doStuff();
    return 0;
}

template<typename T>
void doStuff() {
    T k = 6;
    cout << k << endl;
}
```

Hello. I am stuck with this error. Every time I would get an error that goes like, "Undefined Reference to doStuff". Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: You have to specify the datatype while calling the function!

Answer (score 2):

The declaration of `doStuff()` means a non-template function, the definition is that of a function template, they don't match.

I suppose what you want is function template, then

```
template<typename T>
void doStuff() {
    T k = 6;
    cout << k << endl;
} 
int main() {
    doStuff<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

You can also put the declaratioin before `main()` and the definition after `main()`. e.g.

```
template<typename T>
void doStuff();
int main() {
    doStuff<int>();
    return 0;
}
template<typename T>
void doStuff() {
    T k = 6;
    cout << k << endl;
}
```

Note that you need to specify the template argument when calling `doStuff`, because it can't be automatically deduced.

Comment: This answer would benefit from an example of how you can forward-declare the function template so it doesn't have to be defined before the call.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a template function, type name is expected while the function is being called.

For **int**

```
doStuff<int>();
```

For **char**

```
doStuff<char>();
```

So the program looks like

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template<typename T>
void doStuff() {
    T k = 6;
    cout << k << endl;
}


int main() {
    doStuff<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What extra you did @Quentin

Comment: See [songyuanyao's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44042265/3233393).

Comment: Please read the question, did he ask to explain it, he just asked for the solution @Quentin

Comment: Put another way, your fix [does not work on its own](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df1ba742ffb3ca91), because it doesn't solve the mismatched declaration issue in OP.

Comment: Now that's a constructive comment, I'll edit my answer to "Remove the forward declaration" (Y) @Quentin